# How to create hidden SSID hotspots in Ubuntu 18.04 and above

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, hot-spot

I could see the button to create a hotspot and share the internet from my Ethernet interface. Ubuntu sets a random password and the machine name as SSID.

In older versions I was able to edit the hotspot connection and change the SSID. I can't see that in 18 and above. Should I really need to go with hostapd-dnsmasq solution to create a hidden hotspot?

Is there any way to do this without hassle?

Comment: @K7AAY Ubuntu 18.04 is already mentioned. Is there a relationship with virtualization and hotspots? I am not running Ubuntu inside a virtual environment